# Documentation bug: "An error has occurred during submission; please try again." on one specific topic

Tags: bug, documentation

Here's the change in question:
https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/13612

**Steps to reproduce:** Click on "Approve"

**Expected behaviour:** Change will be marked approved.

**Observed behaviour:** A red message box with the text "An error has occurred during submission; please try again."

**Alternatives tried:**

- problem persists after reload
- problem occurs both in Firefox and in Vivaldi
- problem did not occur when I subsequently approved a different change on a different topic.
- the proposed change remained in the queue

**Question for who reads this:** could you follow the link and try to approve the change yourself? Does the problem occur for you, too?

Comment: I had the same issue on this change a few hours ago.

Comment: I had the same problem trying to reject it.  A call to `map()` does not return a list in all versions.  Since the title of the topic says `All versions`, the edit is inappropriate.  **Edit**: As pointed out by the editor, it is indeed appropriate since it is meant to be Python 2 code testing the difference between it and Python 3.

Comment: Repro on chrome 51, linux.

Comment: Even rejecting it fails!

Comment: I have the same issue on http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/64724?draftId=54417

Comment: Again: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/89011

Comment: Same here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/95553